# How can I link an app page to a website on Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode12

I'm a beginner in programming and am trying to make a simple app for displaying a webpage after choosing from menu options. However, I'm having trouble linking the code window to the storyboard, especially for linking a new page for the app to a new class. I think it's partly b/c I can't view the code and storyboard side by side.

I've also written code for displaying the website in on an app page, but I'm getting an error message saying "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" (code below). Any tips on how I can address these?

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

//class ViewController: UIViewController {

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
        
        override func loadView() {
            webView = WKWebView()
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            view = webView
        }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad() {
                let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
                webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

Above should be:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

without the inner brackets.

Comment: Thank you, there wasn't an error in compiling; however, a web browser is not appearing on that app page. I'm not able to call it using code such as "@IBOutlet var great: UIView!

Comment: Hi, I'm able to connect a button to a URL on the original ViewController which will take the user to the website. However, when I try to do so with a new Cocoa Touch Class to forward a new button on a different View Controller, the same code does not work and the button does nothing.